# How to install sink with overflow hole and tube?

Tags: plumbing, drain, sink, overflow

I am installing a drain, and the old drain system has a overflow hole with a tube connecting it to the drain.

The new one has no part for the tube to connect to the drain, I think I need a part for this.

[image: picture of tube and drain]

Comment: More info is needed. Why can you not reuse the tail piece that has the connection for the overflow? What is the reason for a new drain?

Comment: I am installing a new sink fixture, with new faucet and levers so I want the drain's color to match the new sink. Sadly the old piece with the connection broke as I took off the old drain.

Comment: Most new sinks have the overflow built into them, so no external tube is needed. Can you post a link to your new sink?